# Error with returning multiple index from a list using listbox multiselect

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

New to VBA and somewhat frustrated. trying to make a form for my fellow teachers to simplify paperwork.

I have a list in a form
1. apple
2. orange
3. grape

If the user were to select apple and grape from the list, I want the cell to have just the indexes. So to print (1,3) in the cell. I don't want the words.

My current code

```
Private Sub SpedAccomAddBtn_Click()

'variable to count multiple selections'
VarSped = " "

'loop to keep track of indexes of selected items'
For X = 0 To Me.SpedListBx.ListCount - 1 'count through list
    If Me.SpedListBx.Selected(X) Then    
        If VarSped = " " Then  'if blank then record first item'
            VarSped = Me.SpedListBx.ListIndex + 1 'first selected item. +1 because excel is a 0 based index'
        Else 'if not the first selection add a , between selections'
            VarSped = VarSped & "," & Me.SpedListBx.ListIndex + 1
        End If
    End If
Next X

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master SPED Sheet").Range("c4") = VarSped 'print to cell'
```

If i use the earlier example of choosing Apple and Grape, I get (3,3) not (1,3). I can't figure out why VarSped keeps getting overwritten.
(I am new to coding and I have to comment everything so I feel like I know what I'm doing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and see how to refer to the current item inside the loop:

```
Private Sub SpedAccomAddBtn_Click()

Dim VarSped As String
Dim x As Integer

'variable to count multiple selections'
VarSped = " "

'loop to keep track of indexes of selected items'
For x = 0 To Me.SpedListBx.ListCount - 1 'count through list
    If Me.SpedListBx.Selected(x) Then
        If VarSped = " " Then  'if blank then record first item'
            VarSped = Me.SpedListBx.List(x) 'first selected item. +1 because excel is a 0 based index'
        Else 'if not the first selection add a , between selections'
            VarSped = VarSped & "," & Me.SpedListBx.List(x)
        End If
    End If
Next x

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master SPED Sheet").Range("c4") = VarSped 'print to cell'

End Sub
```

Comment: this for me returns the values (1. apple, 3. grape) and not (1,3)

Answer (score 0):

your loop iterator is your item position already: just add one to it to manage the 0-based List:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub SpedAccomAddBtn_Click()
    Dim VarSped As String ' a string is always initialized with a null string, i.e. with a "" string. hence no need for a 'VarSped = ""' statement

    Dim X As Long
    For X = 0 To Me.SpedListBx.ListCount - 1 'count through list
        If Me.SpedListBx.Selected(X) Then VarSped = VarSped & "," & X + 1
    Next

    If VarSped <> vbNullString Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master SPED Sheet").Range("c4") = Mid$(VarSped, 2) ' print 'VarSped' only if user selected something (i.e. 'VarSped' is not a not string). Mid$() function is used to skip the first character which is a colon 
End Sub
```

Get in the habit of placing `Option Explicit` at the very topo of every module and explicitly declaring all your variables: this will both save you a lot of debugging time and give you much more control over your code

Comment: I think I understand the code. so the selected(x) command returns the index, I was using the wrong commands. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. `Selected(X)` is returning whether the `X`th element is selected or not, where `X` is the index itself